# Are there any glaring vulnerabilities in this example token-creation contract?

Tags: tokens

https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code

If I were to deploy that, or something very similar to it, would I be at risk of any obvious exploits or is it actually alright? Not that my play token will have any value, of course, but still I wouldn't want someone being able to come along and use `transferFrom` to compel some token holder to send them all their tokens, for example.

At first glance, there's nothing anyone can do with tokens other than those they legitimately hold, right?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's right and you can be sure if in the future there will be any exploits found the code will be fixed and updated on the site.

Use the code with confidence and deploy it on the test network.